# Shopify app store listing redirected unexpected URL

Tags: shopify

I have created app and published to list on shopify App store. But it goes to wrong link when any user click on "Get" button from publishing link.

In App setting there are APP URL and Redirection URL. From publishing link it goes to App Banner link instead of redirection URL however it working fine if I install app from server link.see the difference between these two links.

https://apps.shopify.com/2c2p

https://bizziq.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks on the "Get" button from the Shopify App Store they are going to be redirected to the app URL that you registered in the partner dashboard.

Your server can then redirect the merchant to the  `/admin/oauth/authorize` page, as described in [the OAuth documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth#asking-for-permission). If the merchant doesn't have your app installed then they will see [the install screen.](https://help.shopify.com/assets/images/api/oauth-app-permissions.png)